# Optaplanner - ConstraintProvider not found if in submodule

Tags: optaplanner

Still trying to run Optaplanner on our projects, today I tried to separate in multi modules our applications but got some troubles with Optaplanner.

So we have multiple gradles modules that looks like this:

- app -> Contains the @SpringBootApplication
- referentialdata -> Contains almost all our entities / repository / etc
- auth -> Contains the authentication logic
- simulation -> Contains the solver logic

And they are all under the parent build.gradle file

It seems that if I move my `ConstraintProvider` from the base module (app) where the `SpringBootApplication` is to another module (simulation), then I go this error.. All the other solver related things (like the SolverConfig.xml, the SolverService where I invoke the solver are already in the simulation module), the `SpringBootApplication` is well scanning the packages containing the `ConstraintProvider` as the entities and repositories under the same package are detected

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig]: Factory method 'solverConfig' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No classes found that implement EasyScoreCalculator, ConstraintProvider or IncrementalScoreCalculator.
Neither was a property optaplanner.score-drl defined, nor a constraints.drl resource found.
Maybe your ConstraintProvider class  is not in a subpackage of your @SpringBootApplication annotated class's package.
Maybe move your constraint provider class to your application class's (sub)package.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

Here is my configuration (the paths are good):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
    <solutionClass>com.api.simulation.impl.domain.optimizer.AllocationProblemSolution</solutionClass>
    <entityClass>com.api.simulation.impl.domain.optimizer.OptimizerAffectation</entityClass>

    <termination>
        <secondsSpentLimit>160</secondsSpentLimit>
    </termination>

    <scoreDirectorFactory>
<!--        <scoreDrl>com.api.simulation.optim/rules.drl</scoreDrl>-->
            <constraintProviderClass>com.api.simulation.impl.AllocationConstraintProvider</constraintProviderClass>
    </scoreDirectorFactory>
</solver>
```

Is there a way to make it work in submodules or should the constraint provider be in the main module ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "module" and "submodule". Maven? JPMS? Something else?

Comment: @LukášPetrovický I edited my message, we are using Gradle

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that this is intentional, and it also hints at what you need to do to fix that:

```
Maybe your ConstraintProvider class is not in a subpackage of your @SpringBootApplication annotated class's package.
```

It's been a while since that code was written, and we are currently evaluating  whether or not we still need to place that limitation on users. I will update my answer here if/when we decide to change the behavior.